# Plotting Vector Arrows from U and V Component with ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, map-algebra

I have two raster layers representing the U and V components of a vector wind. I could generate the magnitude raster by applying Square root in Map Algebra in ArcGIS.

I also generated a raster layer of wind direction by two formulas:

```
x = ATan2(-v, -u) / (2*3.14159265) + 1

(x - Int(x)) * 360
```

How can I plot Vector Arrows from U and V Component with ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: Can you provide an image of what the end result would look like?

Comment: Yes, I plotted two raster layers (direction and magnitude)

Comment: In your question

Comment: Does http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/17/displaying-speed-and-direction-symbology-from-u-and-v-vectors/  help at all?

Comment: I provided raster layers of direction and magnitude but i want to generate arrow vector wind. I don't know how can do it

Comment: I was extracted u850 and v850 winds component from MERRA nc files and imported them as separated layers then calculated angels and magnitude with Algebra.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ArcMap 10.3 or higher you can symbolize magnitude and direction with the vector field symbology method. Information about how to set up this display method is found in the help file [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/drawing-raster-data-using-vector-symbols.htm).